# Mitsubishi Lancer 2016

Tags: ac, mitsubishi, motors, lancer, air-compressor

I Had recently given my car for major service at Mitsubishi dealership
After the car has arrived i have got this weird issue in my car
At approximately 125 km/h, when the AC is on, there is a vibration kind of a sound similar to that of something opening and closing like a motor or something
But it sounds like a mobile vibration
It stops after one time vibration and the car can go higher speed after this say 130
Again when the car drops the speed from 130 to 120, at 125 there is this l vibration sound again as if there's some sort of a speed sensing flap or something opening and closing happening in there near the right hand passenger side.
Can someone help me what can be this.. Please note it only comes when AC is on
Is it the compressor gas
​​​​​​​Or can it be some heat flaps or something opening up at 125 or something

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What was the major service being done to the vehicle? Is your speed actually limited or does it just feel like it isn't gaining speed at the point you're talking about?